# Как сделать переключатель между способами передачи параметра в функцию: переключатель для [ref]

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-word, параметры

Для автоматизации обработки документов использую скрипт Powershell и готовые документы Excel,Word с макросами.
Пример кода вызывающего нужный макрос:

```
    switch($type) {
        'docx'{ 
                $app = new-object -comobject word.application
                $doc=$app.Documents
                $macros="procedureDoc"
            }
    
        'xlsx'{ 
                $app = new-object -comobject excel.application
                $doc=$app.Workbooks
                $macros="procedureXls"
            }           
        }

$doc.open($macros_file)     # открытие документа

$app.run ($macros, $param1) # запуск макроса с передачей параметра

$doc.close                  # закрытие документа

$app.quit()                 # закрытие приложения
```

При передаче параметра в VBA-процедуру в Word нужно использовать **[ref]**

```
$app.run ($macros, [ref]$param1) # запуск макроса с передачей параметра
```

Без этого возникает ошибка:

> Аргумент "2" должен быть System.Management.Automation.PSReference.
> Используйте [ref].

Кроме этого, в одних версиях MS Office нужно использовать эту опцию, а в других - нет.

**Как решить задачу**: в коде скрипта переопределять класс **ref**, менять параметр
**$param1** или др.?

P.S. Код *$param1=[ref]$param1* - не рабочий. Можно конечно добавить ещё одну проверку **switch**, но хотелось бы попроще.

Answer (score 0):

А если все в switch вставить

```
PS C:\Users\alHaos> $useRef = $true
PS C:\Users\alHaos> .($useRef ? {Write-Warning "[ref] used"} : {Write-Warning "[ref] not used"})
WARNING: [ref] used
PS C:\Users\alHaos> $useRef = $false
PS C:\Users\alHaos> .($useRef ? {Write-Warning "[ref] used"} : {Write-Warning "[ref] not used"})
WARNING: [ref] not used
PS C:\Users\alHaos>
```

Comment: Собственно, в комментарии я указал ,что **switch** я и сам могу вставить в коде где угодно. Речь о том ,чтобы уменьшить количество кода. В Вашем коде, фактически, идёт дублирование строк (создания документа, закрытия и выхода). А так надо заводить глобальную переменную, которая будет говорить, когда [ref] использовать, а когда нет (в зависимости ещё и от версии Office). А поскольку передача параметров происходит несколько раз, появляется много (на мой взгляд) лишних **switch**. Я полагаю, есть более изящное решение. Подумываю использовать [scriptblock], чтобы использовать [ref] опционально

Comment: Могу предложить вот такое решение, будет работать с шестой версии powershell

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, технически использование **Write-Warning** - это уведомление пользователя о состоянии переменной. Взаимодействие с пользователем: остановка, приостановка, прекращение исполнения скрипта. Как это поможет вызывать функцию с нужным параметром, мне не понятно.

Comment: Это пример компактного выполнения скрипт блоков в зависимости от условий .($useRef ? {'script block if $useRef -eq $true'} : {'script block if $useRef -eq $false'})